# Регулярное выражение для поиска пустых тегов

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, xml

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска всех тегов без закрывающего, например, `<br>`.

Нужно найти и заменить все подобные теги на более валидный вариант вроде `<br/>`.

Мое знание регулярок не позволяет такое написать.

**Из комментариев:**
У меня из-за своего уникального велосипеда грузится шаблон HTML. Потом достается необходимое и пихается в XML.Вот тут то и нужна валидация

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что это более валидный вариант? Какой версии `doctype` используете?

Comment: А не проще было бы сначала пройтись по html парсером с возможностью исправления/удаления кривых тегов, а потом превратить результат снова в строку?

Comment: Вы сначала список всех тегов напишите, которые могут быть с закрывающей косой и которые надо менять. а потом этот список `|` разделите и регулярка практически готова

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Возможно проще.Но скорость упадёт скорее всего  :(

Comment: @VenZell XML требует

Comment: @Mike А если теги имеют внутренности?Например `meta` с атрибутом `charset`.Регулярка же сломается?

Comment: @Maksym, укажите точный doctype, пожалуйста. Или у вас именно XML, а не HTML?

Comment: ну да, значит ее надо будет под это строить. но основная проблема что в регулярке надо учесть все теги описанные в стандартах, что бы теги которые имеют пару не пытаться закрывать. Так что я бы сказал работа на неделю минимум. И лучше такое делать не регулярками

Comment: @VenZell У меня из-за своего уникального велосипеда грузится шаблон HTML. Потом достается необходимое и пихается в XML.Вот тут то и нужна валидация

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, ознакомьтесь со [**списком пустых элементов по спецификации**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements).

> area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input,
>   keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

Во-вторых, смиритесь с тем фактом, что регулярные выражения не подходят для решения данной задачи. Некорректную разметку нормально за вас обработает [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php). Проблем с переносом атрибутов тоже не будет.

Вот рабочий пример (он же на **[Ideone](http://ideone.com/kS2laB)**):

```
<?php
/* Все возможные пустые элементы */
$void_elements = explode(', ', 'area, base, br, col, hr, img, input, wbr, link, meta, param, source, track, embed, keygen');
$html_string = '<div class="demo">';

foreach ($void_elements as $void_element) {
  $html_string .= "<div class='element'><{$void_element} content='bla-bla'></div>";
}
$html_string .= '</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($html_string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

echo $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
```

Результат (отформатированный):

```
<div class="demo">
  <div class="element">
    <area content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <base content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <br content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <col content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <hr content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element"><img content="bla-bla" /></div>
  <div class="element">
    <input content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <wbr content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <link content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <meta content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <param content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <source content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <track content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <embed content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <keygen content="bla-bla" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Обратите внимание на флаг** `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`.

Без него вывод (отформатированный) был бы таким:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="demo">
    <!-- Тут остальное содержимое... -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Начиная с версии PHP 5.4 и Libxml 2.6 в методе [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/ru/libxml.constants.php) появился второй параметр `$option`, который поясняет Libxml, как следует парсить HTML

> LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED (integer)
>   Устанавливает флаг `HTML_PARSE_NOIMPLIED`, который отключает автоматическое добавление недостающих html/body... элементов.

Все предопределенные константы можно посмотреть в [**документации**](http://php.net/manual/ru/libxml.constants.php).

### Внимание

Хотя в документации указано, что требуется Libxml версии 2.6, однако `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` доступен только с версии 2.7.7.

Кроме того, несколько идущих подряд пустых элементов могут приводить к некорректной разметке.

Вот рабочий пример (он же на **[Ideone](http://ideone.com/fUTLbi)**):

```
<?php
$void_elements = explode(', ', 'param, source, track, embed, keygen');
$html_string = '<div class="demo">';

foreach ($void_elements as $void_element) {
  $html_string .= "<{$void_element} content='bla-bla'>";
}
$html_string .= '</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($html_string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

echo $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
```

Результат (отформатированный):

```
<div class="demo">
  <param content="bla-bla" />
  <source content="bla-bla">
  <track content="bla-bla">
    <embed content="bla-bla">
    <keygen content="bla-bla" />
    </embed>
  </track>
  </source>
</div>
```